# Changing the collection based on the request type

Tags: express, collections, model, mongoose-schema

This controller accepts the form and updates the data.

```
export const createPost = async (req, res) => {
const { title, message, selectedFile, creator, tags } = req.body;

const newPostMessage = new OrangeModel ({ title, message, selectedFile, creator, tags })

try {
    await newPostMessage.save();

    res.status(201).json(newPostMessage );
} catch (err) {
    res.status(409).json({ message: err.message });
}
```

}

I want to change the collection type based on the request.

when the request is from the Grapes url, the model(or collection) should change to **GrapeModel** from **OrangeModel**. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a `POST /Grapes` to be behave differently from a `POST /Oranges`, you can attach your controller to both paths and evaluate the path inside your code.

```js
const createPost = async (req, res) => {
  let newPostMessage;
  if (req.path === "/Oranges") newPostMessage = new OrangeModel(...);
  else if (req.path === "/Grapes") newPostMessage = new GrapeModel(...);
  try {
    await newPostMessage.save();
  ...
};
app.post(["/Oranges", "/Grapes"], createPost);
```

Answer (score 0):

Also I got the answer like this:

```
exports.createPost =Model=> async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const doc = await Model.create(req.body, {
      new: true,
      runValidators: true,
    });
    res.status(200).json({
      status: 'success',
      data: {
        doc,
      },
    });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({
      status: 'fail',
      message: error,
    });
  }
};
```

Here just call createPost function with the model name